# How to multiply a 3D matrix with a 2D matrix efficiently in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have two multidimensional arrays, which I want to multiply with each other. One has the shape N,N,3 and the other has the shape N,N.

Let me set the stage:

I have an array of atom positions of the shape `N,3`:

```
atom_positions = [[x1,y1,z1],
                  [x2,y2,z2],
                  [x3,y3,z3],
                  ...       
                            ]
```

From these I calculate an upper triangular matrix of distance vectors so that the resulting N,N,3 matrix contains all unique pair distance vectors `r_ij` of the vectors inside `atom_positions`:

```
pair_distance_vectors = [[[0,0,0],[x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1],[x3-x1,y3-y1,z3-z1],...],
                         [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]            ,[x3-x2,y3-y2,z3-z2],...],
                          ...
                                                                              ]
```

Now I want to normalize each of these pair distance vectors. For that I want to use my N,N `pair_distances` array, which contains the length of every vector inside `pair_distance_vectors`.
The formula for a single vector is: 
r_ij/|r_ij|

I want to do that by doing a matrix multiplication, where every entry in the N,N array becomes a scalar by which a vector inside the N,N,3 array is multiplied. I'm pretty sure that this can be achieved somehow with numpy by using `numpy.dot()` or a different function, but I just can't find the answer myself. Also, I'm afraid if I do find a transformation which allows for this, that my maths will be faulty.

Here's some demonstration code, which achieves what I want in a very inefficient fashion:

```py
import numpy as np

pair_distance_vectors = np.ones(shape=(2,2,3))
pair_distances = np.array(((1,2),(3,4)))
normalized_pair_distance_vectors  = np.zeros(shape=(2,2,3))

for i,vec_list in enumerate(pair_distance_vectors):
    for j,vec in enumerate(vec_list):
        normalized_pair_distance_vectors[i,j] = vec*pair_distances[i,j]

print(normalized_pair_distance_vectors)
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Maybe this is clearer:

```
distance_vectors = [[[x11,y11,z11],[x12,y12,z12],[x13,y13,z13],...],
                    [[x21,y21,z21],[x22,y22,z22],[x23,y23,z23],...],
                    ...                                            ]

distance_matrix = [[r_11,r_12,r_13,...],
                   [r_21,r_22,r_23,...],
                    ...                 ]

norm_distance_vectors = some_operation(distance_vectors,distance_matrix)

norm_distance_vectors = [[r_11*[x11,y11,z11],r_12*[x12,y12,z12],r_13*[x13,y13,z13],...],
                         [r_21*[x21,y21,z21],r_22*[x22,y22,z22],r_23*[x23,y23,z23],...],
                          ...                                                    ]
```

Comment: `np.multiply.outer(pair_distances,vec)`?

Comment: That does seem to produce the correct result, but like 4 times in a 5D array or something. I want to combine pair_distance_vectors and pair_distances, not pair_distances and vec. Would that also work?

Comment: Why would it produce 5D array? It should be 3D array same as normalized_pair_distance_vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need a loop. Trick is to expand your `pair_distance` in the 3rd dimension by repeating it `m` times (`m` being the dimension of your vectors, here 3D) and then divide two arrays element wise (works for any `m`-dimensional vectors, replace 3 with `m`):

```
pair_distances = np.repeat(pair_distances[:,:,None], 3, axis=2)
normalized_pair_distance_vectors = np.nan_to_num(pair_distance_vectors/ pair_distances)
```

Output for your example inputs:

```
[[[1.         1.         1.        ]
  [0.5        0.5        0.5       ]]

 [[0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333]
  [0.25       0.25       0.25      ]]]
```